# Sending audio to a bluetooth enabled speaker, IOS

Tags: bluetooth, core-audio, speaker, a2dp

I want to add a function to my App, where the user can choose to play the audio on a bluetooth enabled speaker. I have a Parrot Easydrive in my car and this works for phonecalls and for example the Dictafoon App among others.

I understand that I should use the Core Audio framework. WHen a bluetooth device is connected it is said that it is easy to stream the audio to that connection. I am now looking for Core Audio sample code (or a book) where connecting and streaming to a bluetooth device with Core Audio is explained.

Can anyone shed a light on this? If there is another framework or sample code which I can use please mention it!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You don't write any specific Core Audio code, it is the same process as is used to play audio via AirPlay.

Basically you put a [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) into your UI, and the underlying framework will redirect your audio output for you. Once you implement this you will be able to use Bluetooth and any AirPlay enabled device with your app.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow Marcel, be sure to mark the question as answered by ticking the 'tick' if the answer helps you out.

Comment: I didn't think the OP would mark it as answered. Hopefully it helps someone else though.

Comment: There is no problem with audio play, there is problem with no choise for selecting output device