# Send audio to bluetooth device with AVPlayer IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Hey I have a video app which uses AVPlayer, I received an email from a user saying he couldn't use his car's bluetooth anymore since I updated the app some time ago.

Now, I didn't tried to support bluetooth back then, but apparently this functionality came along with MPMoviePlayerController which I used before.

Is there a way to check if there's a bluetooth device connected and to send audio to it?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082182/sending-audio-to-a-bluetooth-enabled-speaker-ios), but it didn't help, the volume control shows but no button letting me chose the output.

Do I have to do something else in order to use bluetooth as output?

I've only tested with my car's bluetooth, which works with phone calls and also other apps like Viber.

Comment: It required a Bluetooth headset that supports A2DP profile.

Comment: @Emanuel: i am also having same issue with my app, issue with sending audio to connected bluetooth device. Can you help me how did you fix it?